# How to avoid using instanceof in MVC Architecture

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, refactoring, instanceof

I'm developing a game like Pacman in Java and I am currently facing these code smells which I do not like.

Let me explain my thinking: my game is set up on a MVC architecture. On the view module I look for every power-up that is on the model and add it to the elements list to be drawn on the GUI. The problem is that I have 3 types of power-ups that use an interface, so when I am adding the power-ups I need to check what type are they and then add the correspondent view. Let me show some code so I can be clearer:

```java
for (PowerUp powerUp : level.getPowerUps()) {
   if (powerUp instanceof Invincibility) elements.add(new InvincibilityView(powerUp.getPosition()));
   if (powerUp instanceof Freeze) elements.add(new FreezeView(powerUp.getPosition()));
   if (powerUp instanceof Fright) elements.add(new FrightView(powerUp.getPosition()));
}
```

The second smell is related to the ghosts, my game has a State Pattern, and it is suposed to change the ghost's color if the state is changed. For example, if the state is `Frightened` I want the ghosts to be orange, if the state is `Frozen` I want the ghosts to be blue, etc.

So when creating the Ghost View I pass the state by argument, and it checks (again with `instanceof`) what state is currently on. Let me show some more code:

```java
public void draw(graphics) {
    String color = "#FF0000";
    if (state instanceof Invincible) color = "#585858";
    if (state instanceof Frozen) color = "#00FFFF";
    if (state instanceof Frightened) color = "#FF7F50";
    // draw ghost
}
```

My question is how to avoid using `instanceof` without changing my model module.

Stay Safe!

Comment: You're probably looking for an Abstract Factory. Note that `ViewFactory` can have a method `canHandlePowerup(PowerUp)`, and then you can iterate over a list of factories to find the one that handles a specific powerup and ask it for a view.

Comment: Did you try to use interface for actions and enum for colors?

Comment: I tryed the solution pointed out by @chrylis-onstrike-, I now have factories for every ghost and powerUp view, and a FactoryProducer which selects the correct factory from a list. This what I was looking for indeed, I now have a lot of new files but the code is expandable with ease just by adding new factories. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a very common problem to solve when you aim at segregating concerns. For instance, if rendering wasn't segregated from the model then you'd have a `PowerUp.render()` method so they can render themselves and call it a day.

However, you'd then have another problem where all sorts of concerns would end up in a single class. It's a trade-off, you either implement the operations directly on the objects or you extract those behaviors, but then have to perform type matching in some way.

The abstract factory can be interesting here as it reduces the number of type-based decisions you will have to make, but should you need to make other type-based decisions (e.g. different power-up sounds), you will have to type-match again and there's no way out of it.

That being said, you could implement a reusable type-safe mechanism for type-matching using the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

e.g. (access modifiers left out for brevity)

```
interface PowerUpVisitor {
    visit(Invincibility powerUp);
    visit(Freeze powerUp);
    visit(Fright powerUp);
}

interface PowerUp {
    accept(PowerUpVisitor visitor);
    ...
}

class Freeze implements PowerUp {
    accept(PowerUpVisitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}

class PlayPowerUpSound implements PowerUpVisitor {
    visit(Invincibility powerUp) { playInvicibilitySound(); }
    ...
}

class RenderPowerUp implements PowerUpVisitor {
    visit(Invincibility powerUp) { renderInvisibility(); }
    ...
}

//In practice you would most likely reuse the same visitor instances
somePowerUp.accept(new PlayPowerUpSound()); //to play sound
somePowerUp.accept(new RenderPowerUp()); //to render
```

The main advantage of this pattern is that now the compiler will tell you if you've forgot to handle a specific type of power-up, unlike the instanceof checks.

With dynamic type-based resolution like in the other proposed abstract factory solution, you'd have to implement runtime-based validation using reflection to make sure a factory exists for all types.

The Visitor Pattern often comes to mind naturally for hierarchical structures like abstract syntax trees, but it's just as useful here.

There's also other ways if you agree to make the segregation less strict. For instance, you could introduce a specialized interface for the various behaviors a `PowerUp` may have, such as `IPlaySound`, `IHaveAView`, etc. and implement these operations in the powerups directly. The boundaries are now drawn solely by interfaces, but they still exist.

Finally, you could also ask the powerups for their respective renderer or sound player instead of having the operation carried out by the object directly. I think I prefer the visitor here, but there's many ways to skin a cat depending on the complexity you expect, etc. It's all about trade-offs!

Comment: This was very helpful, I must say I wasn't familiar with this pattern, but I'm just getting started on OOP. I think this is even better for me than the abstract factory. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Pattern matching comes from functional programming and the visitor pattern is the OO implementation of it. Perhaps java will offer a syntax for that in the future, but it's not that much boilerplate. Also note that abstract factory is generally for a family of objects. E.g. WindowsUIComponents vs MacUIComponents where both allows youbto create OS specific buttons, windows, etc, not just a single component.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking for is the Abstract Factory pattern. There are several ways to implement it; this may be the best match for what you need:

```
interface ViewFactory<V extends View> {
    boolean canHandlePowerUp(PowerUp target);
    V createView(PowerUp target);
}

class FreezeViewFactory extends ViewFactory<FreezeView> { ... }

...

List<ViewFactory<? extends V>> factories;

View v = factories.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.canHandlePowerUp(p))
    .findFirst()
    .map(f -> createView(p))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no ViewFactory found for " + p);
```